# How to group some functions into a new memory section of .exe output in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++, compiler-construction, linker

I need to use Visual C++ to build a customized Apache web server. Here is the goal I am trying to achieve: specify some of the functions or data in Apache source code, and put them in separate and 4k-page aligned sections (not .text .data .bss) of output .exe file.

The closet solution I can find online is use /Gy compiler options to compile each functions into different COMDATs, and then use /ORDER linker options to put the COMDATs in a predetermined order. However, it is just reordering inside a section, not changing the section layout in .exe output or creating a new section. Under Linux, I can use compiler attribute "section" and linker script to fulfill my goal. Are there equivalent solution in Visual C++? Thanks very much:-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`#pragma code_seg`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s20kdbse%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) lets you specify the segment into which code will be placed. Along with being able to specify a name, the compiler keeps a stack of names so you can push and pop the current state if you want.

Comment: After I put functions and data into different page-aligned sections, can I later put them into consecutive memory region? How can I do that? For example, say I have text1, text2, data1 sections in a.o, text3, text2, data2 sections in b.o, and a.o, b.o is linked to create c.exe. How can I make sure that the memory layout in c.exe is (text1, text2, text3, data1, data2, .text, ........)?

Comment: @cyclone: I'm not at all sure you can. If that was supported, the module definition file would be the obvious place to support it -- but it doesn't.